# Apache Apex - Kafka 0.9 secure kafka topics

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-apex

Can someone pls help me understand,

Does apache apex have any inbuilt kafka input operator to read from Kafka 0.9 secure kafka topics?

Answer (score 3):

Apex does support Kafka 0.9. You can read Kafka topics using KafkaSinglePortInputOperator. Below is the link to an example usage of this operator.

https://github.com/DataTorrent/examples/blob/master/tutorials/kafka/src/main/java/com/example/myapexapp/KafkaApp.java

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Apache Apex has operators to read from secure kafka 0.9 clusters.

I would suggest you to build your malhar jar from github repo as there are recent fixes added on connecting to secure 0.9 kafka clusters. Check the below link.

https://github.com/apache/apex-malhar

Comment: You may use the latest release from malhar now which has the fixes